# input same line as echo batch file

Tags: networking, command-line, batch

Cannot seem to get this exactly right, trying to setup a batch file to do some network commands, such as ping. I have the following code:

```
echo Please enter the IP Address to TELNET 
echo IP Address:
set /p IP_Addr=
```

I can't seem to get the input for IP Address on the same line as the echo. I tried using echo|set, but don't know if I've used it correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, lost formatting when posted question. Each "echo" is on a different line, and "set" is on a different line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `set /?`:

> SET /P variable=[promptString]

The prompt you want to display for the `set /p` goes after the equals sign.

So:

```
echo Please enter the IP Address to TELNET 
set /p IP_Addr=IP Address:
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. :)  Note you can put a space after it too, and it'll include that space in the prompt (to put a gap between the colon and their input), so it looks nice. ;)

Comment: Excellent, I will give it a try!